# I get this error when trying to autoload classes

Tags: php, autoload

I get this error when trying to autoload classes.

I declare this class in myclass.php file and instantiate it in test.php. but i got class not found error on xammp. Is _autoload function case sensitive in php.

```
class MyClass {
//some properties and methods
}

function __autoload($class_name) {
require_once($class_name.".php"); 
}

$myclass = new MyClass();
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you define `MyClass` correctly in your `myclass.php`.Your problem is not caused by `__autoload` because the error is `class not found` instead of  `file not found` which `require_once` would throw out if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Class names and function names in PHP are not case-sensitive, but your autoloader must use the correct case when using `require*` or `include*` because your OS filesystem may be case-sensitive. And if your autoloader uses relative paths, make sure the classes invoked are in PHP's `include_path`.